# how do I modify my topology to follow the path I want instead of what it already is?

Tags: topology

When pressing Ctrl + Alt + RtMouseButton to see what the topology is then seeing it is not travling in the direction one wants. How to I figure out what to do to redirect it to the path I want it to take?

take this image for example. Say I want it to have topology so that it follows under the breast then upwords so it has a bra strap effect.

what are the rules of thumb to know where to cut it and re-attach the squares to get the desired effect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have it torn down a bit now, trying to figure this out.

I'm not totally sure how important how the topology is set up on a modle, because I have seen more then one pattern for the same area. This leads to confustion. I have not gotten past this phase yet into the adding color, texture, then boning of a modle to know how the boning effects whatever way it was topolog-ized prior to adding a bone structor to the modle.

I just do not want to run into a problem when adding bones then finding the movment is not life like. Having the modle bend in odd ways.

Comment: If you could upload your file and add a drawing of the wanted topology on the picture, that can help to answer. You can upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon added information requested to main post.

Comment: Normally, a retopo can rely on the original model. If you have kept the one without the holes (like in your last picture) I could rely on it, so that I don't modify its shape... here, as there is holes... I cannot guaranty it will have the exact same shape. Please tell me if you can do that or not before I do it

Comment: By the way... why do you want to change it like that ? In order to have clothes at this exact same place ?

Comment: @lemon I have no idea what I am doing. this is my first attempt at this.

Comment: if this is your very first attempt, let me say this is great ! I don't know how to write an answer about that, except to say "the job is done"... so I will give your file back here. I cannot say this is the best possible, but I have followed your instructions, I think... After that, you may google image about topology and follow the links to learn (particularly for the ears : )) ! [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1828" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1828/).

Comment: Placing vertices for clothes is not generally recommended. If you want simple cartoon clothes this might barely suffice with undesirable edges.  Consider painting simple clothes, face and body textures as a next step.  Consider separate clothes meshes in the stressful future.

Comment: @lemon the body part is like the second time I created it. I'm using Manuel Bastioni Laboratory Modle for a how to guild on topology. that head I've mangled too many times to count. Noticed them ears I C .. lol .. results of frustration kicking in. that sheer mesh look in wireFrame mode makes it hard to see  though ...

Comment: You seem to be requesting tutorial information on topology.  I suggest searching here at BSE.  See the BSE resource page.  On the site with name that rhymes with NooNoob, consider searching .... Blender Topology.  A tutorial here would be lengthy and your question will be served better by long video supplements.

Comment: @ atomicbezierslinger yes I have watched a hand full of youtube blender how tos on  topology that is why I asked this question, I think I even mentioned the fact I've seen it done different ways so I was looking for a human responce from someone that has first hand experience in this. How much will it effect the movment of the model when animating it (if i ever get that far)

Answer (score 2):

For proper Retopology, it is recommended to keep the original mesh as a mere foundation of the shape. And then start with a new object from scratch and apply the desired topology.

Here is a relatively easy way how to do good retoplogy without using any third party addons:

- **Step 1:** Create your Base Model. The Toplogy is unimportant at this point. It also can be a sculpted mesh with a high polycount. But make sure it does not slow your system too much down:

  [image]
- **Step 2:** Create a new object and open the edit mode.
- **Step 3:** Enable "snap during transform" and set it to "Face" 

  [image]
- **Step 4:** Select a vertice point and hit <kbd>G</kbd>. Snap it to the desired position.

  [image]
- **Step 5:** Form the desired shape of your topology.

  [image]
- **Step 5:** Continue to form the topology and connect edges.

  [image]
- **Step 6:** Go on until you are done.

  Also here is a list of some good topology references: https://de.pinterest.com/demons_fate/mesh-toplogy/

Answer (score 1):

**Rotate Selected Edge**

[image]

You will have options for Clockwise or Counter Clockwise.

5 edge poles affect flow in your topology.  You already have 5 edge poles for changing flow in your model.  Sometimes extrude or inset produces 5 edge poles.  This tool will allow you to experiment with more 5 edge poles easily and quickly.  You can undo quickly as well.  Edit mode for the mesh.

Control+e .... <kbd>Control+e</kbd> brings up the menu..

[image]

Below two operations of rotate edge on a symmetrical plane grid.  The result is a flow change as illustrated.  Technique, not artistry, is demonstrated.  Note the production of 5 edge poles.

[image]